# ORA-01536: space quota exceeded, but more than enough in my schema

Tags: oracle

When I try to create a table, I get an error that I don't have enough table space. But the number of tables in my schema adds up to 3.9 GB, and I have 20 GB of table storage. Anyone have any idea why this might be?

For context, this is the output when I put in the code 
select * from user_ts_quotas

```
TABLESPACE_NAME  BYTES       MAX_BYTES    BLOCKS  MAX_BLOCKS  DROPPED
USER             4427481088  10737418240  270232  655360      NO
USER_OLD         0           5368709120   0       327680      YES
```

When I put in the code:

```
SQL> select t.tablespace_name,
  2    u.username,
  3    sum(s.bytes) / (1024 * 1024) free_MB
  4  from user_tablespaces t join user_free_space s on s.tablespace_name = t.tablespace_name
  5       join user_users u on u.default_tablespace = t.tablespace_name
  6  group by t.tablespace_name, u.username;
```

I get the output:

```
TABLESPACE_NAME  USERNAME    FREE_MB
USER             MY_SCHEMA   55036.9375
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe there's enough space on disk (or whatever "20 GB" represent), but - do you, as user, have enough space in your default tablespace? What does such a query return?

```
SQL> select t.tablespace_name,
  2    u.username,
  3    sum(s.bytes) / (1024 * 1024) free_MB
  4  from user_tablespaces t join user_free_space s on s.tablespace_name = t.tablespace_name
  5       join user_users u on u.default_tablespace = t.tablespace_name
  6  group by t.tablespace_name, u.username;

TABLESPACE_NAME                USERNAME                          FREE_MB
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
USERS                          SCOTT                             97,0625

SQL>
```

If there's no enough space, you can connect as a privileged user (such as SYS) and do something like this:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> alter user scott quota unlimited on users;

User altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: My default table space is 20 GB-if you're referring to the amount of storage I have in my schema. The error message is ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'User'. It says I have 54638.9375 free MB based on the above code.

Comment: Perhaps the available space is fragmented and only exists in chunks smaller than the initial extent you need.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, or how to check that.

Comment: I'm not a DBA so I'd rather keep my mouth shut; Google for "defragmentation" or ask for assistance on DBA Stack Exchange.